# Vehicle Routing Problem not utilizing all available routes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, routing

I have a Vehicle Routing Problem with:

- 319 orders, each with specific delivery quantities
- 8 depots
- 105 routes, all with the same capacity
- 840 route renewals, one for each route at each depot

Upon solving, only 273 orders are serviced by 47 routes utilizing 157 route renewals.

Can anyone explain why the remaining 58 routes were not used to serve the remaining 46 orders?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you figure it out?